# Angular2: convert array to Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs

I have a component that gets the data from a service via http, the problem is that I don't want to hit the API backend every time I show this component. I want my service to check if the data is in memory, if it is, return an observable with the array in memory, and if not, make the http request.

My component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from 'angular2/core';
import { Router } from 'angular2/router';

import { Contact } from './contact';
import { ContactService } from './contact.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'contacts',
    templateUrl: 'app/contacts/contacts.component.html'
})
export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit {

    contacts: Contact[];
    errorMessage: string;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private contactService: ContactService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getContacts();
    }

    getContacts() {
        this.contactService.getContacts()
            .subscribe(
                contacts => this.contacts = contacts,
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
            );
    }
}
```

My service

```js
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from 'angular2/http';
import { Contact } from './contact';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class ContactService {

    private contacts: Array<Contact> = null;

    constructor(private http: Http) {

    }

    getContacts() {
        // Check first if contacts == null
        // if not, return Observable(this.contacts)? <-- How to?

        return this.http.get(url)
            .map(res => <Contact[]>res.json())
            .do(contacts => {
                this.contacts = contacts;
                console.log(contacts);
            }) // eyeball results in the console
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }


    private handleError(error: Response) {
        // in a real world app, we may send the server to some remote logging infrastructure
        // instead of just logging it to the console
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You're right there. If you already have the data in memory, you can use [`of`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/of.md) observable (equivalent of [`return/just`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/return.md) in RxJS 4).

```js
getContacts() {

    if(this.contacts != null) 
    {
        return Observable.of(this.contacts);
    } 
    else 
    {
        return this.http.get(url)
            .map(res => <Contact[]> res.json())
            .do(contacts => this.contacts = contacts)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably a dumb question but couldn't you just cache the observable itself and call .next() rather than caching the state and recreating the observable on each call?

Comment: Good point, I'll try it. Though it my not be the best for when I want to iterate the array to return a single contact by a specific key

Comment: import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

Comment: @Eric Martinez, thanks for your answer. Where do you get the of from. I imported that from 'rxjs' however it is not in the Observable.

Answer (score 52):

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';
    
return of(this.contacts);
```

Answer (score 16):

In angular7 its enough to just put the `of()`. Whatever you put inside
`of()` will be changed to observable. Here, `this.contacts` is converted
to observable.

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';

getContacts() {
    if (this.contacts != null) {
        return of(this.contacts);
    }
}
```

Comment: This leads to: 
Error: Module not found: Error: Package path ./add/observable/of is not exported from package ...\node_modules\rxjs (see exports field in ...\node_modules\rxjs\package.json)

Answer (score 15):

Some people like me want it differently, which is from `string[]` into `Observable<string>`.

This is an example which involves the conversion:

```typescript
import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toArray';

const ids = ['x12', 'y81'];
let userUrls: string[];

from(ids) // Converting string[] into Observable<string>
  .map(id => 'http://localhost:8080/users/' + id)
  .toArray()
  .subscribe(urls => userUrls = urls);
```

Hopefully it will help some others.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution here:

```js
getSomething(): Observable < Object[] > {
    return new Observable(observable => {
        this.http.get('example.com').subscribe(results => {
            observable.next(results.json());
            observable.complete();
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be extremely late in coming, but I've been using `sessionStorage` pretty heavily to handle some of my work.  If you lose state because people were bouncing around, you still have your data.

```html
getSubjects(): Observable < Subject[] > {
    let SubjectsString = sessionStorage.getItem("Subjects");

    if (SubjectsString) {
        let subjects: Subject[] = JSON.parse(SubjectsString);
        console.log("GETTING DATA FROM SESSION STORAGE");
        return Observable.of(subjects);
    } else {
        let url = `${this.apiHost}/api/subject`;
        return this.http.get(url)
            .map(res => {
                sessionStorage.setItem("Subjects", JSON.stringify(res.json()));
                return res.json();
            });
    }
}
```

In this example, I've got a class for Subject and a definition for apiHost, but the rest is pretty simple.  You call the service for an observable.  Your component has no idea where the data is and it doesn't care.  The service checks local storage and, if it has it, converts it into an observable and returns it, if it doesn't, it goes and gets it, then saves it to local storage and then returns it.

In my case, I have some huge applications with hundreds of pages.  Users might bounce from a nice new Angular4 page, over to a classic ASP age and back again multiple times.  Having all menu items and even search results in sessionstorage has been a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Observable.of(resultArray);`

from the `import { Observable } from 'rxjs;'` package

Comment: This leads to "Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.ts(2339)"