# Http request made multiple times in Angular2 service

Tags: http, angular

I have created a service that makes a simple GET request:

```
private accountObservable = null;

constructor(private _http: Http) {
}

getAccount () {
    // If we have account cached, use it instead
    if (this.accountObservable === null) {
        this.accountObservable = this._http.get('http://localhost/api/account')
            .map(res => <Account> res.json().data)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    return this.accountObservable;
}
```

I have added that service in my bootstrap function to provide it globally (my hope is to provide the same instance to all components):

```
provide(AccountService, { useClass: AccountService })
```

The problem is when I call this service in different components, a GET request is made every time. So if I add it to 3 components, 3 GET requests will be made even though I check if an observable already exist.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._accountService.getAccount().subscribe(
    account => this.account = account,
    error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error
  );
}
```

How can I prevent the GET request to be made multiple times?

Comment: Are you only `provide`ing the service at the bootstrap level?  (It sounds like you might be listing it in the `providers` array in all of your components, which would create 3 instances of your service).  If you only provide it at the bootstrap level, try using [Observable.share()](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/share.md).  (These are all just guesses on my part.)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/35527616/215945 for a slightly different implementation of caching a server result.

Comment: Yes, I only do `provide` on bootstrap. I have tried adding console.log() in construct of the service and it's only fired once. I added `share()` after `get()` but it made no difference. The other post didn't work either. I guess it's because until we have received data, a new request will be made. So if 3 components are running getAccount() at the same time all will make requests and it won't stop until one of them have got response.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`Observable.share()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/share.md):

```
if (this.accountObservable === null) {
    this.accountObservable = this._http.get('./data/data.json')
      .share()
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L2eHKy2mZg4oTwxL6PMy?p=preview)</kbd>

In the Plunker, AppComponent and Component2 both call `getAccount().subscribe()` twice.

With `share()`, the Chrome Developer tools Network tab shows one HTTP request for `data.json`.  With `share()` commented out, there are 4 requests.

Comment: This doesn't work.  Saw this problem a while back, and this solution, seeing it again, solution still doesn't work.

Comment: Also don't forget to add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';` @RickO'Shea This answer works perfectly well. If it doesn't work for you then you might want to post a plunkr that demonstrates your problem with it.

Comment: on newer rxjs you need to use `pipe` so need to update to: `.get(...).pipe(share(), map(...))`. source: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html

Comment: Here's an updated answer @RickO'Shea and others still trying to figure this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60081534/4843137

Comment: I added share method inside pipe I worked code: .get(...).pipe(share(),

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of observables.

Cold Observable : each subscriber receive all the events ( from the begining )

Hot observable : each subscriber receive the events that are emited after subscription.

Cold Observables are the default one. That's what the WS calling is triggered many times.

To make an Observable Hot you have to use following Rx's operators chain :

```
.publish().refCount()
```

In your case :

```
getAccount () {

    let accountObservable = this._http.get('http://localhost/api/account')
            .map(res => <Account> res.json().data)
            .catch(this.handleError);

    return accountObservable.publish().refCount();
}
```

Comment: But won't this still result in an HTTP request each time `getAccount()` is called?

Comment: there is an error `Property 'publish' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because of form post and button clik was set to same listener

Answer (score 0):

The updated solution is:

1) Change your getAccount() method to use `share`:

```
getAccount () {
    // If we have account cached, use it instead
    if (this.accountObservable === null) {
        this.accountObservable = this._http.get('http://localhost/api/account')
            .pipe(share())
            .map(res => <Account> res.json().data)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    return this.accountObservable;
}
```

2) Add `import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';` to the top of your `.ts` file to get rid of the error on `share`.