# Angular2 - Rxjs Subject run twice even after unsubscribing

Tags: angular, rxjs, subject-observer

I'm writing a desktop application using angular2 and electron and there is a download functionality.

My `DownloadService` is this

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from "rxjs";

interface IQueueItem {
    url: string
}

@Injectable()
export class DownloadService {
    private queue: Array< IQueueItem > = [];

    private downloadSubject: Subject<any>;

    constructor() {
        this.downloadSubject = new Subject();
    }

    addToList(item: IQueueItem) {
        this.queue.unshift(item);

        downloadList();

        return this.downloadSubject;
    }

    downloadList() {
        // pick one item from queue and send it to electron to download and store

        // do this every time a chunk of data received
        this.downloadSubject.next(evt);
        ...
    }

    pauseDownload(item) {
        // send an event to electron to it should stop downloading and therefore no chunk of data will receive
        // also remove item from queue
        ...
    }
}
```

And my `ItemComponent` is this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {DownloadService} from "../services/download.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-item',
    template: `
        ...
      `
})
export class ItemComponent {
    constructor(private downloadService: DownloadService) {
        this.addToQueue();
    }

    subscription;

    downloadedBytes = 0;

    fileUrl = '';

    pause() {
        this.downloadService.pauseDownload(this.fileUrl);

        this.subscription.unsubscribe();

        ...
    }

    resume() {
        this.addToQueue();
    }

    private addToQueue() {
        this.subscription = this.downloadService.addToList(this.fileUrl)
            .subscribe(evt => {

                console.log(evt.delta);

                this.downloadedBytes += evt.delta;
            });
    }
}
```

The problem is when I pause an item I unsubscribe from `Subject` passed from `DownloadService` but when I resume again, every `console.log()` prints twice and add twice data to `downloadedBytes`.
Also if I pause and resume again, It will add more and more bytes and logs!

I searched but I couldn't find any clue to solve.

Comment: My guess is that it comes from the fact that downloadList() adds the component to a list. But since we don't know what this list is for, when the subject emits events, what it is used for, what pauseCourse() does, etc., it's hard to explain. Provide a complete example reproducing the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet sorry I did lots of simplification and apparently the result was not good. I added more details

Comment: I can't reproduce it https://plnkr.co/edit/64mn6U1omy8JPE6LD4Nf?p=preview. Check also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673582/http-request-made-multiple-times-in-angular2-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see from the [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/64mn6U1omy8JPE6LD4Nf?p=preview) created by [**yurzui**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5485167/yurzui) that if you **resume** and **pause** everything works as expected, triggered only **once**. 
The issue is when you click **resume 2 times in a row** as the **first** subscription will be lost in the memory and only the **second** one will be stored in **this.subscription** the access to the first one is lost and you cannot unsubscribe.


This is more like an app issue than rxjs, you should not be able to click resume if the subscription is not paused, so you need to handle the states properly, something like this (edited from @yurzui plunker) :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Angular 2 Systemjs start</h1>
    <button *ngIf="started && !paused" (click)="pause()">Pause</button>
    <button *ngIf="started && paused" (click)="resume()">Resume</button>
    <button *ngIf="!started" (click)="start()">Start</button>
  `
})
export class App {
  constructor(private downloadService: DownloadService) {
    this.addToQueue();
  }

  subscription;
  downloadedBytes = 0;
  started = false;
  paused = false;


  pause() {
    this.paused = true;  

    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  start() {
    this.started = true;  

    this.addToQueue();
  }

  resume() {
    this.paused = false;

    this.addToQueue();
  }

  private addToQueue() {
    this.subscription = this.downloadService.addToList(this)
      .subscribe(evt => {

        console.log(11);

        this.downloadedBytes += evt.delta;
      });
  }
}
```

You can find a working example in this updated [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/UO9tjcexiFbUHnqpCeXu?p=preview)